# What does 战斗机 in this line mean?

Tags: meaning, word

> 他的花心只是为了成为备胎中的战斗机.

It has something to do with a guy being a spare tire, but what about "fighter jet?"

Comment: cf。 ?下蛋公鸡，公鸡中的战斗机！Oh Yeah~！
baidu： 就是公鸡也能下蛋,这可是在公鸡中少见的啊,形容稀奇吗,那个OH YEAH 就是高兴自信吧...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"fighter jet" is something originally from an ad that was popular many years ago:

波导手机，手机中的战斗机

The ad aims to emphasize the extent to which their cell phones are more superior than others (fighter jets are much faster than normal jets). It had repeated many times for a long period, so many people got to know it very well. Since then, "fighter jet" is also used in other cases, such as the case you mentioned "备胎中的战斗机". Here it means "the best spare-tire among all the spare-tires".